# White space between slides bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap carousel for a slider on the home page of a website.

When the carousel slides automatically there is no problem but as soon as I click the next and prev arrows a ±140px wide white space appears between the slides.

I have inspected the css and removed all white space in the HTML but I'm having no luck at all.

Carousel HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix row slider">
<div class="clearfix carousel slide col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-example-generic">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="clearfix item active" style='background: url("/Content/Images/media/carousel/hero-test.jpg") no-repeat;'>
            <div class="clearfix max-width carousel-caption">
                <h2>Hello. I'm Lorem. I'm a Slow
                Cooker.</h2><span class="clearfix">And I'm quickly
                changing the world</span> 
                <a class='fresco cta' data-fresco-caption="Lorem | How It Works" data-fresco-group='example' href='https://vimeo.com/105705114'>How It Works</a>
            </div>
            <video autoplay="" class="bgvid" loop="" poster="/Content/Images/default/video-bg.jpg">
                <source src="/Content/Images/media/bkvideo/1_Lorem-marquee.mp4" type="video/webm">
                <source src="polina.html" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix item" style='background: url("/Content/Images/media/carousel/1_marquee-2.jpg ") no-repeat;'>
            <div class="clearfix max-width carousel-caption">
                <h2>Get to know Lorem.</h2><span class="clearfix">And learn the Lorem Story</span>
                <a class="cta" href="/Pages/SarahsStory">Meet Lorem</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-generic"><span><img alt=" " src="/Content/Images/default/arrow-slider.svg"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-generic"><span><img alt=" " src="/Content/Images/default/arrow-slider.svg"></span></a>
</div>
```

Link to website: http://bit.ly/1BcaEb8 - Click on South Africa and its the main carousel / slider

Comment: On your link there is no slider, please make a workign fiddle, that we can assist you:)

Comment: It's the main banner / slider on the home page. Please click on South Africa.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what the problem was. I had custom CSS `.left{float:left;}` and `.right{float:right;}`

When the carousel slides it adds classes of left and right to the containing div. Removed the left and right floats in my CSS - problem solved :)

Comment: Yep, I had something quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

set carousel-inner overflow to visible.

```
.carousel-inner{overflow:visible}
```

Comment: This removes white space but now to the left of the carousel (it's on the right of the page) the old image now goes over the to of the other content on transition.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has by default CSS for carousel which provides 0.6s transition delay.
This transition shows white spaces between two slides
Inorder to hide those white spaces we need to remove transition by rewriting  the css and using !important to make it work.

*bootstrap.css*

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

**style.css**

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    -webkit-transition: 0s !important;
    -o-transition: 0s !important;
    transition: 0s !important;
}
```

copy the above code (style.css) in your external or internal css and hide those white spaces

Answer (score 0):

I faced up same issue. We need to display previous slide on transition.

```
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left{
  display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sacrifice some of your width:

```
.carousel-item {
  width: 99%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers solve my issue. This is what I did remove that gap between images.

Add two properties inside of your

> .carousel-item

```
.carousel-item{
    float:none; 
    transition: 0s !important;
}
```

This will remove the gap and also the image switching slides animation/transition.

Answer (score 0):

just replace the carousel-inner to carousel then see the magic